# Why parent Component can change Input.value with setState?Doesn`t input have it`s own state?

Tags: reactjs

As we know,parent Component can not change child Component state,because state is independent and private! And the Official documents also said "In HTML, form elements such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select> typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input",then why we can use this.setState({value:this.value+1}) in parent Component to change ???I was confused about this!

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 100};
    setTimeout(
      () => {
      this.setState({value:(this.state.value+1)});
      },
      1000
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <inpt value={this.state.value} />
     //value will change from 100 to 101
     //if here is a user-defined component,we must use 
     //componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){this.setState({value:nextProps.value})}
     // to update child component,but the DOM component doesn`t need!why??
     //Does DOM component  hasn`t it`s own state?

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Parent cannot change the state but you can pass props from parent to child and in child use that props to setState.

Comment: Are you asking why we cant use `this.setState({value:(this.state.value+1)});` in a parent component to set the state in a child component?

Comment: I mean why we can update DOM component directly but we must use componentWillReceiveProps to update user-defined component, they all have their own state!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the same page, you get the quote, react mentions that the form inputs are a `Controlled Components`, which means that the parent component of them can affect there state and it can know some information of their current state, as the `onChange` listener on the input, the parent component will know when the input is changed and what its new state for the value.

the opposite of this is the `uncontrolled components` which is a component that the parent may not know anything about its current state, as the image slider in a page, the page doesn't know what is the images that the slider renders, and it doesn't know which image is active now, until you add a handler like `onImageChange`, which will tell the page which image is the active now, and by that you turned it from uncontrolled component to a controlled component.

**Recap**:

**the controlled component**: a component that changes its own state, based on parent component props values, and can share some of its state information with the parent component by the callbacks that the parent passes to it as props.

**the uncontrolled component**: a component that doesn't change its own state, based on the props that passed to it from the parent, and doesn't share pieces of its state with the parent by the callbacks that the parent passes to it as props.

I hope that answered your question.

Comment: If It seems like the answer for my question,but i can not get it from official doc. directly.

Comment: you can read this for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html